# How to define a custom Application theme to specify a default background for a layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I am creating a default theme for our Android apps to specify default custom theme to be applied to the whole app. The idea is we shouldn't have to specify appearance related attributes in the layout and they should be automatically injected by applying the custom theme to the entire app.

I am able to do this for UI widgets like `TextView` and `EditText` by overriding their styles.
For example overriding `android:textViewStyle` and `android:buttonStyle`, etc.
How can I do the same for a layout (`LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, etc) so that I can specify a default background for a layout?

The application element in android manifest looks like this:

```
....
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_title"      android:allowBackup="false" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme" android:name="MyAppClass">
```

Theme.MyCustomTheme looks like this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="Theme.MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/my_custom_text_view_style</item>
  <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/my_custom_edit_text_style</item>
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/my_custom_button_style</item>
  <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/my_custom_list_style</item>
```

The custom styles above inherit from the respective android base styles.

I am looking for the right android attribute to use above to  override the style of a layout so that I can apply my custom default background to every layout (`LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, etc) declared in the layout `xml` file without having to explicitly specify it in the layout xml. I tried overriding `android:colorBackground` but that didn't make any difference. I tried overriding `android:windowBackground` but that changes the color of the action bar as well. Please note that I am using the `appcompat` theme from the appcompat support library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to define a custom default background for every container layout in my application

1. First, I defined a a custom theme as a style with the app compat background as the parent background  which overrides the default window background. Please note that I am using the theme from the Android compatibility library to support pre-honeycomb Android devices

   ```
    <style name="Theme.MyCustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

       <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/my_custom_window_background</item>
       <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/my_custom_window_background</item>

   </style>
   ```
2. I applied the above theme to the whole application in the  AndroidManifest

   <
   application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_title"      android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCustomTheme"/>
3. The above steps  resulted in every window having my default window background color defined in step 1 above including action bar. I definitely did  not want my action bar, edit text, text view etc  to be the default window color. So, I needed to to go back to step 1 and override the style of specific UI widgets I did not want to have the default window background

   ```
     <style name="Theme.MyCustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/my_custom_window_background</item>
      <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/my_custom_window_background</item>
      <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/customMenuColor</item>
       <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/customTextViewStyle</item>
       <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/customEditTextStyle</item>
       <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/customButtonStyle</item>
       <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/customListViewStyle</item>
       <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/customTabWidgetStyle</item>
       <!-- Support library compatibility -->
       <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/customActionBarStyle</item>
       <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/customMenuColor</item>
   ```
4. The last step was to define the  each custom style define above either to have custom styles for them or have then assigned the system default styles (overridden because of custom window background)

For example, the custom action bar style will look like this:

```
<style name="customActionBarStyle"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">@color/light_black</item>
       <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
       <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/customActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
       <!-- Support library compatibility -->
       <item name="background">@color/light_black</item>
       <item name="displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
       <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/customActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>
```

5. The advantage of this approach is you can define a default theme in a centralized way and don't have to define a background for each layout as it will be injected through the  custom theme applied to the entire app.. Any future re-theming of the app will be very easy with this approach

Please refer to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme) on  theming including how to theme the action bar for more information

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) i didn't see anything applicable to layouts and `ViewGroups` in general, (although there are styles support for lists and some widgets as you can see).

Therefore I am not sure that it is possible to have your custom style applied to all layouts.

I guess you would still have to apply your custom layout style, (where you could change background color as

```
<item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
```

) to each of your layouts yourself.

Feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Overriding  android:background will change the background of every UI element, not just the layouts. I have tried that and messes up the whole UI. If you see my custom styles, they override the styles applicable to specific elements.  I want to do the same for  Linear, Relative layouts etc, but can't figure out how to override style applicable to a layout (a UI layout inheriting from a ViewGroup).

Comment: @user3465654 I updated my answer, I am afraid you can't have what you want

Comment: overriding the android:background is not the solution for me. The idea itself is to inject the background to each layout without explicitly having to specify it for each layout. I'll keep researching how to achieve this.

Comment: you don't have to specify background for each layout if you specify it in your style and then set style for each of layouts. Please let me know if you find an alternative solution.

Comment: @kiruwkna, If possible, I don't want to even specify a style for each layout and want it to be injected automatically (just like I can do it for TextView by overriding android:textViewStyle in my theme. looks like there is no equivalent for a Layout/ViewGroup in general. What I am going to try next is override windowBackGround in my theme, but that will change the color of the action bar  as well, so I'll need to override actionBarStyle to control its background. I guess it will need some trial and error.